# How to leverage a variable set in a FOR LOOP to access an array?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, batch-file

I have my array definition setup as such (trimmed down for example purposes):

```
FOR %%a IN (
        "Japan|JPGLPAL|JP10|inbox/JAPAN-PL|Japan-PL DLR"
        "Japan|JPGLBAL|JP10|inbox/JAPAN-BS|Japan-BS DLR"
        ) DO (
FOR /F "tokens=1-5 delims=|" %%A IN (%%a) DO (
    SET "STR[%%B].REGION=%%A"
    SET "STR[%%B].ENTITY=%%C"
    SET "STR[%%B].DM_INBOX=%%D"
    SET "STR[%%B].DM_DLR=%%E"
```

So then when I try to access the array from a variable I set within another for loop, it doesn't work obviously since I'm only using %% instead of !! on DATAFILENAME.  How would I get this to work?

```
    FOR %%a IN ("%FDMEE_BIN_TEMP%*") DO (
        SET "DATAFILENAME=%%~nxa"
        ECHO Data File  :  %%~nxa
        ECHO Region     :  !STR[%DATAFILENAME:~0,7%].REGION!
        ECHO Entity     :  !STR[%DATAFILENAME:~0,7%].ENTITY!
        ECHO DM Inbox   :  !STR[%DATAFILENAME:~0,7%].DM_INBOX!
        ECHO DM DLR     :  !STR[%DATAFILENAME:~0,7%].DM_DLR!
        ECHO Start POV  :  %STARTPOV% 
        ECHO End POV    :  %ENDPOV%
        ECHO. & ECHO.
    )
```

I don't think it's possible but can string manipulation be done on %%~nxa without setting it as a variable first? maybe that would work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, string manipulations aren't possible on FOR meta-variables.

To solve your problem, you need an intermediate FOR variable.

```
FOR %%a IN ("%FDMEE_BIN_TEMP%*") DO (
    SET "DATAFILENAME=%%~nxa"
    ECHO Data File  :  %%~nxa
    for %%P in ("!DATAFILENAME:~0,7!") DO (
      ECHO Region     :  !STR[%%P].REGION!
      ECHO Entity     :  !STR[%%P].ENTITY!
      ECHO DM Inbox   :  !STR[%%P].DM_INBOX!
      ECHO DM DLR     :  !STR[%%P].DM_DLR!
    )
```

Comment: Jeb, this was the ticket!!  Thank you so much for a quick answer. I've updated my process to accomodate the new process.